# Change Kodi user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kodi

I have installed kodi on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After installing I have the usual ~/.kodi folder for user "user1" and kodi runs with no problems. Is it possible to either:

1.) Change the user from "user1" to "user2"

2.) Create a new user "user2" for kodi

I then want to be able to run kodi under the new user "user2".

Is any of this possible?

(To be clear "user2" already exists on my Ubuntu system.)